# Error adding a delimited text layer

Tags: qgis, layers, csv

Im working with QGIS 1.8.0 and I have been trying to upload a delimited text layer but keep getting the following error :

The layer file:///C:/Users/fernando/Desktop/ATLAS/TAMAULIPAS/Estaciones%20Meteorol%C3%B3gicas%20Tamaulipas%20SMN.csv?delimiter=%5B,%5D&delimiterType=regexp&xField=X&yField=Y is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map

I attach you a picture of the settings Im using when uploading the CSV file. Do you have any ideas why could it be wrong?

Thanks in advance. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In QGIS 2.01, there is now a checkbox which enables usage of degree-minutes-seconds.
[image]

Worked for me 2 weeks ago, but at the moment there might be bugs.
In general: This coordinate format is a pain and you should get rid of them as soon as possible, cause there are so many different variations, that it is a horror to create new conversions for them all the time.

For conversion to decimal degrees in Excel, try this formula:

= LEFT(C2,FIND("°",C2)-1) + MID(C2,FIND("'",C2)-2,2)/60 + MID(C2,FIND("''",C2)-2,2)/3600

and substitute C with D for your 2nd coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use degrees-minutes-seconds format in QGIS 1.8.0, only decimal degrees is supported.

Calculating decimal degrees in the csv should be easy using Excel.

Furthermore, I would advise you not to use file names with non-ASCII-characters like é ó .

Comment: non-ASCII-characters file name should work (untested)